# openxml : track changes not found in word document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I parse MS Word documents with OpenXML to find track changes with a Author value in order to blank them. It works except for one particular Word document and I don't know why. Only 6 track changes out of 9 are found.

This is how I look for track changes :

```
 var file = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

  using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true))
  {
    var types = typeof(OpenXmlCompositeElement).Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(p => !p.IsInterface && p.GetProperty("Author") != null && p.GetProperty("Author").PropertyType.Equals(typeof(StringValue)))
                .ToList();

       var body = document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
       var changes = body.Descendants().Where(x =>types.Contains(x.GetType()));
  }
```

Is there a better way to achieve this ?

I have also tried by passing the list of [types found on this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff629396(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but the result was the same. Still these 3 ignored track changes.

**EDIT**

Using Open XML SDK Productivity tool, here's one of the node that should be found as a track change but is missing by the code above :

```
  <w:ins w:id="283" w:author="Mr Smith" w:date="2019-09-11T12:34:00Z">
   <w:r w:rsidR="008458AA">
    <w:rPr>
     <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>
     2
    </w:t>
   </w:r>
  </w:ins>
```

Comment: Could you please post the Word Open XML of one or two revisions that work, and one or two that do not, so that one can compare them? You can use the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool for that. And/or can you think of anything about where these revisions are located / formatted that's different?

Comment: I've added a link in my post. It's a confidential document so I had to remove all the content. But now it's even easier to see the problem. If you open the document in Word you see the track changes with the author. But when I run my code, I see no track changes at all.

Comment: I have used the productivity tool and compared two different doc files (different languages) but with same revisions and they only differ in two places. The one with missing track changes has the following deletion :   /word/footer2.xml, /word/footer3.xml, /word/header2.xml and /word/header3.xml

Comment: see my edit with xml code of missed track change

Comment: Good that you found it, and perhaps now you understand why I asked for the XML that provides the context (which the edit does *not* contain BTW) and where the revisions were located. Note for future questions that providing a link to a document is not useful. I remind you of the site guidelines: all relevant information needs to be *in the question*.

Comment: thanks, I'll remember that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The line `var body = document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;` does not include footer and header !

So I also have to search for track changes within footer and header.

e.g for footer :

```
 var footer = document.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts.ToList();
 var footerChanges = new List<OpenXmlElement>();
                footer.ForEach(f => 
 footerChanges.AddRange(f.Footer.Descendants().Where(x => 
 types.Contains(x.GetType()))));
```